# Simply 301 Redirect /path/ to newdomain.com/newpath/

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

I have a problem on a WordPress website. I want to redirect come URLs to a new domain. I tried with:

```
# BEGIN 301 Redirects
Redirect 301 /old-post/ http://www.newdomain.com/new-post/
# END 301 Redirects
```

The redirect is not working because the user is redirected to:

```
http://www.newdomain.com/new-post/old-post/
```

Here is the `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually state the URL you are wanting to redirect? However, the result you are seeing should not happen with the code you posted, unless you were requesting `/old-post/old-post/`? (`Redirect` is prefix-matching and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target URL.)

However, since you have existing mod_rewrite directives then you should be doing this redirect with mod_rewrite instead of mod_alias - in order to avoid potential conflicts. The mod_rewrite directives will get processed before mod_alias, regardless of the apparent order of the directives in your `.htaccess` file. ie. The URL is first rewritten to `/index.php` and then mod_alias redirects based on the initial request.

You should do something like the following *before* the existing WordPress directives (ie. before the `# BEGIN WordPress` section):

```
RewriteRule ^old-post/$ http://www.newdomain.com/new-post/ [R=301,L]
```

Note the absence of the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Thanks for the help! 

Nothing changed :/ same problem

Comment: And you've cleared your browser cache (and any intermediary caches)? And placed this at the top of your `.htaccess` file? If so, then "something else" elsewhere on your system must be appending the `old-post/` to the end of the redirected URL?! Examine the network traffic - what do you see? More than one redirect? What HTTP status code(s) are you seeing?